# How to build an XML infoset in Java

Tags: java, xml

as i know java can parse the xml file and fetch the data but also i want to know how to create the xml node/nodes and insert value using java.

file: ***myXML.xml***

```
<parent>
    <start> 
       <id> 123 </id>
       <name> s1 </name>
       <value> hello </value>
    </start>
</parent>
```

i want, *to create these nodes `<id> <name> and <value>`* each time, whenever i require to insert the data. suppose if i want to save *id = "456", name = "s2", value = "world"*

file: ***myXML.xml***

```
<parent>
    <start> 
        <id> 123 </id>
        <name> s1 </name>
        <value> hello </value>
    </start>

    <start> 
        <id> 456 </id>
        <name> s2 </name>
        <value> world </value>
    </start>
</parent>
```

please let me know using `java` & if i need to use `dtd` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;

public class Sample {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
      //Read and Parse 
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder builder = dbfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = builder.parse(new File("MyXml.xml"));

      Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
      //Add Element
      Element element_start = doc.createElement("start");
      Element element_id = doc.createElement("id");
      Text textContents = doc.createTextNode(" 456 ");
      element_id.appendChild(textContents);
      element_start.appendChild(element_id);
      Element element_name = doc.createElement("name");
      textContents = doc.createTextNode(" s2 ");
      element_name.appendChild(textContents);
      element_start.appendChild(element_name);
      Element element_value = doc.createElement("value");
      textContents = doc.createTextNode(" world ");
      element_value.appendChild(textContents);
      element_start.appendChild(element_value);
      root.appendChild(element_start);
      //Write
      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
      StreamResult out = new StreamResult(new File("MyXmlOut.xml"));
      TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer tf = tff.newTransformer();
      tf.transform(source, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your options (at least some of the many):

- Use the Streaming API for XML (StAX), package javax.xml.stream
- Use DOM, as said in another answer. Careful with this if the document can get very large (memory).
- Use JDOM or some other DOM-like API that's a bit friendlier towards Java developers. Same warning applies as for DOM.
- Use JAXB.

Whether you need to use DTD depends on who/what is gonna end up using the XML document. You wouldn't require it just to do the Java processing. If possible, use W3C XML Schema instead of DTD.

Comment: Good answer.   I would recommend JAXB for binding data to/from bean objects.  It handles a tree of objects nicely without much fuss on your part.  If you need to conditionally create nodes or modify existing documents then choose [J]DOM for small (less than a few tens of MB) documents or SAX for larger documents (or if the size is unknown at development time.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create or manipulate the XML document using XML DOM API. Take a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT4.html) tutorial.